# "About" at the end of sentence

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

Is this correct to use "about" at the end of the sentence like that?

> I thought all the times this guy must have heard that his music was no good about.

Comment: That sentence is incorrect! What do you want to say?

Comment: @hubbledeepfield I just wanted to put "about" at the end. This is the original sentence: "I thought about all the times this guy must have heard that his music was no good."

Comment: @hubbledeepfield can it not be used the word "good" as a noun so that noun is here?

Comment: Yes, 'no good' is perfectly idiomatic (meaning 'not at all good'). You can't put 'about' at the end of the sentence like that, though. It belongs with 'thought'.

Comment: @KateBunting so is "no good" okay in this sentence?

Comment: Yes it is! I am very sorry I gave you the wrong answer about that part.